# canvas.drawCircle not displaying in for loop

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

The following code works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    Log.e("router size", String.valueOf(routers.size()));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
}
```

However if I change the loop to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < routers.size(); i++) {
    Log.e("router size", String.valueOf(routers.size()));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
}
```

where `routers.size()` equals `1`, the log message still gets written so it's getting into the loop but the *circle* doesn't get drawn.

Can anyone explain whats going on?

I can post my `onDraw()` function and the function my loop is in if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Canvas.drawCircle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) Documentation.

For the parameters, you are passing same values, [`cx` - `100`, `cy` - `100` and `radius` - `50`] as you loop through, so circles are getting over-drawn one over another at same cordinates.

Try with different `cx`, `cy` values, say,

```
canvas.drawCircle(100 * i, 100 * i, 50, paint);
```

will draw each circles at different place.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However the circle isn't being drawn at all. As in my example routers.size() = 1 I would expect the loop to only be executed once and over-drawing not a problem. I'm just stuck as to why I'm not getting any circle at all.